# How to set multiple Qualification criteria for a batch in mechanical turk using python API

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, mechanicalturk

I want to implement the same functionality from Requester end using APIs in python as shown in the image below:

[image]

I want to test if Hit approval rate is > 95% for a worker and I also want the worker to Request for qualification so that I could accept / reject accordingly.

I'm done with **Hit approval rate** part but I'm new to this **Request Qualification** stuff.

COde:

```
    new_hit = client.create_hit(
        Title = 'TestABC: Review Semantic Seg 1.',
        Description = "Does the given image have birds in it? Choose 'Yes'. Else choose 'No'.",
        Keywords = 'Yes, No',
        Reward = '0.01',
        MaxAssignments = 1,
        LifetimeInSeconds = 7889238,
        AssignmentDurationInSeconds = 600,
        AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds = 1296000,
        Question = s1,
        QualificationRequirements=[
            {
                'QualificationTypeId':'000000000000000000L0', # Worker PercentAssignmentsApproved
                'Comparator': 'GreaterThanOrEqualTo',
                'IntegerValues': [93,],
                'ActionsGuarded': 'Accept',
            },
            {
                'QualificationTypeId':'00000000000000000040', # Worker hits approved
                'Comparator': 'GreaterThanOrEqualTo',
                'IntegerValues': [600,],
                'ActionsGuarded': 'Accept',
            },

        ]
    )
```

Could I please get some syntactical help on getting the **Request Qualification** part and make worker ask for permission as shown in the image (Third Qualification criteria on bottom right)? Couldn't get this part from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The "request qualification" link is inserted by the MTurk site itself for workers that don't yet have the Qualification Type. (Those that already have it will see their score/value).

If you create a Qualification Type yourself, and add it to a HIT, Workers will see this link. You'll then need to grant/deny requests you get from Workers. These docs give an overview: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/Concepts_QualificationsArticle.html